# Syntax error on rake db:schema:dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to connect mysql with ruby, I follow this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY7Ps8fqGdc

but on 23:30 in video, I got error with `rake db:schema:dump`,
I have no idea, this is my error:

```
irb(main):016:0> rake db:schema:dump
SyntaxError: (irb):16: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
rake db:schema:dump
               ^
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: As tadman said you need to use the command-line, also called the terminal to execute rake. To leave irb just type 'quit' and enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake` is a command-line tool. It is not supposed to be executed inside `irb` or the Rails console.

Try doing that from the command-line.

`irb` is for evaluating Ruby code only, which is a different thing than the command-line tools like `rails` and `rake` even if they are written *in* Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

At the outset, get out of `irb` console.

[`rake`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) is a build program, similar to [`make`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make). Just go to your project directory on terminal and run your rake commands like:

```
~/apps/myproject$ rake db:schema:dump
```